# How to get only file names from an ls -la (ll) listing?

Tags: ls

I need a long (vertical) list of all file names of all files in a directory.

How to get only file names from an `ls -la` (`ll`) listing?

Only the names, **not**:

```
drwxr-xr-x 9 USER GROUP  4096 Jul 20 10:30 filename1
drwxr-xr-x 9 USER GROUP  4096 Jul 20 10:30 filename2
drwxr-xr-x 9 USER GROUP  4096 Jul 20 10:30 filename3
drwxr-xr-x 9 USER GROUP  4096 Jul 20 10:30 filename4
drwxr-xr-x 9 USER GROUP  4096 Jul 20 10:30 filename5
```

Rather I need only:

```
filename1
filename2
filename3
filename4
filename5
```

Comment: `ls -1` should be the right answer for this question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Printing only filenames is the default behavior of `ls`.  When you add `-l` you are saying you want the "long format" output.  If you just remove `-l` I think that will give you what you want.   You can leave `-a` to include "hidden" files

Also as Stéphane mentioned you could add `-1` if you still want each file on its own line, which will happen with or without `-1` when redirected to a file or piped to another command.

If you want to save this to a file you can use the `>` or `>>` operators as with any command.  See [Redirections](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Redirections) and [What are the shell's control and redirection operators?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/159513/86440)

Comment: `ls -1` seems to me to be what I needed.

Comment: "_you could add `-1` if you still want each file on its own line._" - if you redirect the output of the command to a file or a pipe you'll get one item per line even without this flag

Comment: Ah. I wonder if @user542162 is mis-reading `-l` (letter "L") and `-1` (number one) and assuming they're they same? That could explain part of the confusion I think

Comment: @roaima I just didn't know about `-1` as an option...

Comment: @jesse_b I don't know how to name this, "vertical list"? "Long list"?

Comment: @user542162 I would just describe it as needing each file to be on a newline.  "long list" just describes what `-l` does.

Answer (score 0):

You can redirect the output directly to file by using `>` or `>>`.

E.g. `ls -l > somefile.txt` will create a file called `somefile.txt` containing the results of `ls -l`. Beware, though, as the single `>` will *overwrite everything in the file you redirect to*. Using `>>` will *append* the output to the file you choose to write to.

**EDIT:** `ls -1 >> somefile.txt` is probably the command you are looking for. For *all* files, `ls -1a >> somefile.txt`.

Comment: Sadly it also contains `drwxr-xr-x 9 USER GROUP  4096 Jul 20 10:30` which I want not to take.

Comment: Please check my edit.

Comment: When redirecting the output of `ls`, the `-1` option is not needed.

Answer (score 0):

Piping ls output to cat seems to work in my bash (Konsole) shell. Here is the output from my system.

```
$ ls | cat
bin
boot
cdrom
dev
etc
home
initrd.img
initrd.img.old
lib
lib32
lib64
libx32
lost+found
media
mnt
opt
proc
root
run
sbin
snap
srv
sys
tmp
usr
var
vmlinuz
vmlinuz.old
$
```

The `ls -1` command preserves colorful text in output, whereas the above cat based command looses colors.

Comment: You're getting coloured output likely because you're actually running `ls --color=auto` instead of `ls`, possibly because you have a `ls='ls --color=auto'` alias or `ls() { command ls --color=auto "$@"; }` function in your shell customisation. Note that the fact that you get 1 column when the output goes to a file other than a terminal device (like a pipe) here is already noted in the accepted answer.